# Play framework: How to POST url-form-encoded compound data

Tags: playframework

According to [Play's documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS), this is the way to post url-form-encoded data:

```
WS.url("https://test.com/api/v1/invoice").withAuth("abc", "abc", WSAuthScheme.BASIC).post(
  Map(
    "price" -> Seq("100"),
    "currency" -> Seq("USD"),
    "item" -> Seq("Test")
  )
).map { response =>
  Ok(Json.obj("url" -> response.body))
}
```

The code above works fine. Now I'm wondering how to post compound data structures:

```
 WS.url("https://test.com/api/v1/invoice").withAuth("abc", "abc", WSAuthScheme.BASIC).post(
  Map(
    "price" -> Seq("100"),
    "currency" -> Seq("USD"),
    "item" -> Seq("Test"),
    "custom" -> Map(
      "orderId" -> Seq("112345"),
      "note" -> Seq("A note")
    )
  )
).map { response =>
  Ok(Json.obj("url" -> response.body))
}
```

Of course, this code doesn't work and I get the following compilation error:

```
Cannot write an instance of
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with
PartialFunction[String with Int,Object]{def seq: Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with 
PartialFunction[String with Int,Object]{def seq: Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with
PartialFunction[String with Int,Object]{def seq: Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with 
PartialFunction[String with Int,Object]}}}] to HTTP response. Try to define a 
Writeable[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with 
PartialFunction[String with Int,Object]{def seq: Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with 
PartialFunction[String with Int,Object]{def seq: Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with 
PartialFunction[String with Int,Object]{def seq: Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with 
PartialFunction[String with Int,Object]}}}]]
```

Thnaks.

Comment: It has to be a simple `Map[String, String]` or `Map[String, Seq[String]`. Should the inner map be flattened to something like `"custom.orderId" -> Seq("112345")`, etc ?

Comment: How would you expect the resulting POST body to look?

Comment: Just to let you understand, I'm trying to translate this php snippet: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'price' => 100,
  'currency' => 'USD',
  'item' => 'Book',
  'custom' => json_encode(array(
    'order_id' => '112345',
    'note' => 'A note'
  ))
);

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to invoke the [bips.me](https://bips.me/api/requests) API... an this is the PHP example in their website:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://bips.me/api/v1/invoice");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $token . ":");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        "price" => 20,
        "currency" => "USD",
        "item" => "PDF Book",
        "custom" => json_encode(array(
            "users_email" => $email
        ))
    ));
    $invoiceUrl = curl_exec($ch);
    $app->redirect($invoiceUrl);
```

The **custom** part should be encoded in JSON... so here below is the correct code for invoking their API:

```
WS.url("https://test.com/api/v1/invoice").withAuth("abc", "abc", WSAuthScheme.BASIC).post(
  Map(
    "price" -> Seq("100"),
    "currency" -> Seq("USD"),
    "item" -> Seq("Test"),
    "custom" -> Seq(Json.obj("orderId" -> "112345", "note" -> "A note").toString)
  )
).map { response =>
  Ok(Json.obj("url" -> response.body))
}
```

I hope that helps.